# Parent category as a mainmenu and sub category as a submenu in wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, wordpress

Hai,

I would like to have a parent category as a mainmenu in horizontal view and child categories as a submenu that corresponds to the mainmenu.

For example,

Parent categories as Apple, Orange and Mango

Sub Category for Apple is apple1, apple2, apple3

Sub Category for Orange is orange1, orange2, orange3

Sub Category for mango is mango1, mango2, mango3

So i have main menu as Apple |  Orange | Mango

and when u mouse over Apple then the apple1, apple2, apple3 should be visible at the bottom of the main menu. same for other 2 menus.

Is this possible??
could you guys help me in this??

Answer (score 1):

http://anthologyoi.com/wordpress/displaying-wordpress-categories-in-a-horizontal-dropdown-menu.html

or

http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Horizontal_Menus